# JavaFX project in NetBeans not showing "Libraries" folder. How do I add a jar file to my project?

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans, controlsfx

I'm running NetBeans version 11.1 and a lot of the guides I read suggest adding my jar through the "Libraries" node in the project explorer, but I do not have that entry in the treeview. How do I add a jar (in my case controlsfx) to my JavaFX project?

Comment: Follow https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/. Your focus seems to be `Non-modular` from Netbeans IDE. I would suggest you do `Modular` with Maven Netbeans or `Modular` with Gradle Netbeans. One drawback with the latter is the Automatic Module issue. If you are going to use jars that are designed for Java9 or later you should be okay.

Comment: Will the instructions still apply if I'm using openjfx 8 and openjdk 8? (The latest available version of openjfx on FreeBSD is 8)

Comment: I am not sure. I have never used openjdk 8.